# Formatting Epoch time as Hours Minutes in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Bigquery data source connected to Data Studio.
In a Data Studio table, I wish to display hh:mm of the event (based on the EventTime in BQ).
However it only shows the date correctly, whereas the time is always shown 12:00AM
[image: The table in Data Studio]

This is how I have prepared the calculated field for the "time":
[image: Calcualted field]

What am I missing?

Comment: As per documentation, `TODATE` function can only truncate upto the day level, and not granular than that.

Comment: Hi, I dont see it mentioned here: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300?hl=en. And the output format and examlpes suggest using %H %M etc, which means formatting to hours/minutes should ideally work, isnt it?

Answer (score 2):

When you create your data source, the field "Event Time" should be formatted as "Date Hour Minute" YYYYMMDDhhmm.  If you leave it as default, it will be "Date" - YYYYMMDD, and the time will always be 12:00AM.

Answer (score 1):

The new datetime format of datastudio doesn't support anymore drill down of Date AND time ....
So todate only truncates to day level.
Formatting time only (e.g. %H %M) works, but not if date & time is included.